# Animated bitmaps (APNG) in OTF fonts

Tags: animation, emoji, opentype, apng

The [Open Type font format standard 1.7](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec170/otff.htm) officially supports three [types of colored glyphs](http://blog.fontlab.com/font-tech/color-fonts/color-font-format-proposals/), as required for emojis. As of late 2016, [version 1.8](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec180/otff.htm) has added support for [another variant](https://medium.com/making-faces-and-other-emoji/emoji-fonts-technically-40f3fdc0869e). [Platform support varies](http://stateofwebtype.com/#Color%20fonts):

- Microsoft’s/Mozilla’s [`COLR`](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/colr.htm)/[`CPAL`](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/cpal.htm) tables use standard Truetype [`glyf`](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/glyf.htm) or Postscript [`CFF`](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/cff.htm)  outlines.
- [Mozilla’s/Adobe’s](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/10/svg-colors-in-opentype-fonts/)/[W3C’s](https://www.w3.org/community/svgopentype/) [`SVG`](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/svg.htm)  table uses [SVG](http://www.w3.org/2013/10/SVG_in_OpenType/) outlines and CSS Variables.
- [Google’s](http://github.com/behdad/color-emoji/) [`CBDT`](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/cbdt.htm)/[`CBLC`](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/cblc.htm) tables use embedded PNG bitmaps.
- [Apple’s](http://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6sbix.html) [`sbix`](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/sbix.htm) table uses embedded PNG, JPEG or TIFF bitmaps (and PDFs outside the standard). [Support for masks and aliases](http://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6sbix.html) is planned.

The [`SVG`](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/svg.htm) table explicitly considers animation – using CSS, JS, SMIL or embedded files – but I’m not sure that has been implemented anywhere yet:

> ### [Glyph Rendering](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/svg.htm)
>
> The SVG glyph descriptions may be rendered statically or with animation enabled.

Does any of the **PNG-based implementations support animation** using [APNG](http://wiki.mozilla.org/APNG_Specification)? How about tools?

> ### [Compressed Color Bitmaps](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/cbdt.htm)
>
> Images for each individual glyph are stored as straight PNG data. Only the following chunks are allowed in such PNG data: `IHDR`, `PLTE`, `tRNS`, `sRGB`, `IDAT`, and `IEND`. If other chunks are present, the behavior is undefined.

JFTR, [APNG](http://wiki.mozilla.org/APNG_Specification) relies on three additional chunks which both OS X / macOS and iOS natively support:

- `acTL` *Animation Control*
- `fcTL` *Frame Control*
- `fdAT` *Frame Data*

So, if I’m not mistaken, APNGs should work in `sbix` verbatim, but not in `CBDT`.

Comment: The SVG table approach is certainly live already, although (like all significant OpenType updates) it's a lot of work. Firefox has the widest support at the moment - see the https://pixelambacht.nl/lapislegit font, for nstance.

Answer (score 1):

APNG seems to be supported in [Firefox and Safari only](http://caniuse.com/#feat=apng), so that'll be the same when used as font glyphs.

I figure you already considered this, but if GIF suffices, your best bet would be OpenType SVG. It has the widest support, and you can embed bitmap images in the SVG: see glyph 0050 in [this test font](https://pixelambacht.nl/lapislegit/).

Regarding non-bitmap animations in OpenType SVG, unfortunately you can't use JavaScript animations, and with SMIL on the way out you're stuck with CSS animations... which don't currently work in Firefox and Edge

Comment: I did not seriously consider GIFinSVGinOTF (nor PNGinSVGinOTF). As far as I know, only Firefox currently supports SVGinOTF fully. Other platforms only support basic monochrome outlines, if anything. Opera did support APNG before the switch to Blink, which has a [working patch](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=437662) still awaiting approval so it may be coming back to Opera and finally arrive in Chrome “soon” (if there wasn’t politics favoring WebM/P).

Comment: Windows 10 just recently added support as well, so OpenType SVG works in Edge. And I hope Chrome is to follow soon!

Comment: @RoelN Chrome has an open meta issue for color font support here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=703332